# Custom Decorator for Zend File Element

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form, zend-decorators

I am rendering zend file element using following decorator..

```
$decoratorFile = array
    (
        'File',
        'Errors',
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class'=>'elements')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),       
        array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))
    );
```

But i want to create a custom decorator like the following one...

```
class My_Decorator_Td extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
    public function buildLabel()
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        $label = $element->getLabel();
        if ($translator = $element->getTranslator()) {
            $label = $translator->translate($label);
        }
        if ($element->isRequired()) {
            $label .= '*';
        }
        $label .= '';
        return $element->getView()
                       ->formLabel($element->getName(), $label);
    }

    public function buildInput()
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        $helper  = $element->helper;
        return $element->getView()->$helper(
            $element->getName(),
            $element->getValue(),
            $element->getAttribs(),
            $element->options
        );
    }

    public function buildErrors()
    {
        $element  = $this->getElement();
        $messages = $element->getMessages();
        if (empty($messages)) {
            return '';
        }

        list($key, $error) = each($messages);
        return '<div class="errors">' .
               $error . '</div>';
    }

    public function buildDescription()
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        $desc    = $element->getDescription();
        if (empty($desc)) {
            return '';
        }
        return '<div class="description">' . $desc . '</div>';
    }

    public function render($content)
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        if (!$element instanceof Zend_Form_Element) {
            return $content;
        }
        if (null === $element->getView()) {
            return $content;
        }

        $separator = $this->getSeparator();
        $placement = $this->getPlacement();
        $label     = $this->buildLabel();
        $input     = $this->buildInput();
        $errors    = $this->buildErrors();
        $desc      = $this->buildDescription();

        $output = '<tr>'
            . '<td class="labels">'
                . $label
                . '</td>'
                . '<td class="elements">'
                . $input
                . $desc
                . $errors
                . '</td>'
                . '</tr>';

        switch ($placement) {
            case (self::PREPEND):
                return $output . $separator . $content;
            case (self::APPEND):
            default:
                return $content . $separator . $output;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this one for text elements.

How to create a custom decorator decorator for file element. Any Help?

Comment: Are you going to use this decorator for all the file fields or just for certain number of those (not all)?

Comment: I want to use this for all FILE fileld.

Comment: Is there any problem in this..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer to your question [here](http://mwop.net/blog/217-Creating-composite-elements.html)

Comment: My actual problem is how to create decorator for file elements. Not where to create a file element.

Comment: Actually i want to know how use `FILE` Decorator in this custom decorator.

Comment: Let me clarify.. I want to create a custom decorator for zend file element. Where i can create an html markup for that particular element. Now i don't know how to create it.

Comment: @akond.. Thanks for your support. I look over `Zend_View_Helper_FormFile`. But I think it is used to create a file element. And i want a custom decorator for file element.

Comment: Yes. That's the exactly i want.

Comment: getting error - `No file decorator found... unable to render file element`. And when i add `FILE` decorator along with decorator suggested by you then the element is rendering twice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came up with the solution to create a custom decorator that extends the default File decorator and override the render method to add your markup :

```
<?php

class My_Super_Custom_File_Decorator extends Zend_Form_Decorator_File
{
    public function render($content)
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        if (!$element instanceof Zend_Form_Element) {
            return $content;
        }

        $view = $element->getView();
        if (!$view instanceof Zend_View_Interface) {
            return $content;
        }

        $name      = $element->getName();
        $attribs   = $this->getAttribs();
        if (!array_key_exists('id', $attribs)) {
            $attribs['id'] = $name;
        }

        $separator = $this->getSeparator();
        $placement = $this->getPlacement();
        $markup    = array();
        $size      = $element->getMaxFileSize();
        if ($size > 0) {
            $element->setMaxFileSize(0);
            $markup[] = $view->formHidden('MAX_FILE_SIZE', $size);
        }

        if (Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http::isApcAvailable()) {
            $markup[] = $view->formHidden(ini_get('apc.rfc1867_name'), uniqid(), array('id' => 'progress_key'));
        } else if (Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http::isUploadProgressAvailable()) {
            $markup[] = $view->formHidden('UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER', uniqid(), array('id' => 'progress_key'));
        }

        if ($element->isArray()) {
            $name .= "[]";
            $count = $element->getMultiFile();
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
                $htmlAttribs        = $attribs;
                $htmlAttribs['id'] .= '-' . $i;
                $markup[] = $view->formFile($name, $htmlAttribs);
            }
        } else {
            $markup[] = $view->formFile($name, $attribs);
        }

        $markup = implode($separator, $markup);

        switch ($placement) {
            case self::PREPEND:
                return $markup . $separator . $content;
            case self::APPEND:
            default:
                return $content . $separator . '<div>My Super Custom Markup : '.$markup.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

You should follow the basics to create a custom decorator (prefixPath, etc.) and apply your new decorator to your file element instead of 'File'.